# How can I disable juli logging in tomcat 8?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I am working with a ubuntu web server, where I have tomcat 8 and running a web application on tomcat. Recently I have faced some problem with cpu uses 100%. When I restart the tomcat server it is running good, but after one day or a few hour again same problem arise ( 100% cpu use) and that problem make my site slow. When I see the process list with htop command then i see so many process like

```
/opt/java8/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoader
```

What can i do now? I want to disable tomcat internal logging fully but cannot do this.

What is the function of juli in tomcat? Is it use for only logging? If so i not need any logging. I don't want to see the above process any more. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

[JULI](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html) is Tomcat implementation of java.util.logging API. To turn logging off, in `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties` configure the root logger like this and make sure that there are no child loggers that override this setting:

```
.level = OFF
```